# How to set 'target_list' for the code in NLP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numpy, nlp

```
neg_targets= np.zeros((1000,),dtype=np.int)
pos_targets = np.ones((1000,),dtype=np.int)

target_list = []
for neg_tar in neg_targets:
    target_list.append(neg_tar)
for pos_tar in pos_targets:
    tagret_list.append(pos_tar) 




---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-f966b1bd8054> in <module>
      3     target_list.append(neg_tar)
      4 for pos_tar in pos_targets:
----> 5     tagret_list.append(pos_tar)

NameError: name 'tagret_list' is not defined
```

Comment: Check the spelling of `target_list`

Comment: `tagret_list` should be `target_list`. Please check

Comment: Thank you! I need to do second eye check :)